# How to change the Desktop Manager

Tags: 15.04, kde, lightdm, kdm

When I installed KDE Plasma in Ubuntu 15.04, I set the LightDM as the default manager, But I want to set KDM as the default, how can I change this?

Comment: Take a look [Here](http://superuser.com/questions/376107/how-change-the-default-desktop-manager-in-debian).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To switch between display managers in Ubuntu you can use the command `dpkg-reconfigure`, for example to switch to kdm:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure kdm
```

You'll get a screen that look like this:

[image]

choose the one you want(kdm) and hit enter, then probably you need to make a reboot.

<sub>All rights go  to [owner](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/07/how-to-switch-between-gdm-lightdm-or.html)</sub>

Comment: Or, more generally, `sudo dpkg-reconfigure <dm>`, where <dm> is an installed desktop manager